# JasperServer ROLE problems

Tags: permissions, authentication, role, jasperserver

I have started work on JasperServer community edition for my client.

The problem I face is

1. After creating a new role eg
   "TEST_ROLE"
2. Creating a new user "LADY_GAGA" and
   assigning the user role as
   "TEST_ROLE"

I am getting an error that states

> "You do not have permission to view
>   this page.
>
> Please contact your system
>   administrator or log in as a user with
>   permission."

Please help. I have also assigned the role "TEST_ROLE" its properties such as read, write, delete, access. Am I doing something wrong while assigning or creating a role. You help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to see that page wşth admin account?Can you ensure that you log in to the system as administrator?

Comment: Yes I did log in whilst I was logged in as Superuser. I have logged in as jasperadmin and also as a superuser. But still I get the same problem. I followed the documentation while creating ROLES and assigning its properties. Is there something else that I should do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this one out !

Every user must be assigned a minimal role of "ROLE_USER" and then any other role created and defined by you.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it :-) The thing is my goal was to have a role that granted the user access to only a reduced set of reports. If I assign the user also the role of ROLE_USER then he gets the same access every normal user gets, so it's no use.
Any ideas about how can I get this done?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in http://www.jaspersoft.com/how-set-role-based-jasperserver-home-pages no explain assigned ROLE_USER .

That means that the management of permissions for the TEST_ROL are immune to ROL_USER, which means you can not have a personal ROLE

Answer (score 0):

- First of all set `No Access` permission to the `ROLE_USER` for all the folders and sub folders.
- Now `ROLE_USER` is a role with no permission at all, but keep in mind that `ROLE_USER` should be assign to all users (new and old) for login purpose.
- Create `NEW_USER` with `NEW_ROLE` but `ROLE_USER` also should be assigned to `NEW_USER`.
- Give permission to `NEW_ROLE` as per your requirement. It will surely work.

However you will have to give `Execute Only` permission on all your data sources and input data types for `NEW_ROLE` to avoid `Access is denied` error. Please check and let me know.